# Parsing errors in language files

Tags: joomla-3.x, language

My joomla 3.10 website was transferred to a new server. I get the following error message from the joomla debug console: "JROOT/administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_jdom.ini : error(s) in line(s) 69". How can i fix the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a System Plugin called JDom (plg_system_jdom) has an issue with the new server / PHP version. If you don't need that plugin, disable it (or uninstall it).
If you need that plugin:

- Could you compare the PHP versions and server settings from both servers?
- Could you switch on Joomla's debug mode (in Global Configuration) and post the  detailed error info here?